# PySpark - How to output JSON with specific fields?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

The JSON format looks like:

```
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "address": {
    "street": "blv abc",
    "street_num": "122"
  }
}
```

I would read the data from parquet files and execute a sql query on them, like finding all those living at street `blv abc`. But I just want to output the `name` and `address.street` as:

```
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "address": {
    "street": "blv abc"
  }
}
```

How can I output only `name` and `address.street`?

The DataFrameReader schema might not work for me since I need to execute some SQL query before output which might need to filter on `street_num`.

Comment: What exactly would you like to do? convert JSON to a new JSON without street_num? can you please provide your code, showing what did you try to do?

Comment: `record = sqlContext.read.parquet("file.json")`
`sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(record, "record")`
`sqlContext.sql("select * from record where street == 'blv abc'")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last resort for this kind of unusual data transformation is

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

def transform(row):
    d = row.asDict()  # now in python data types

    del d['address']['street_num']

    return Row(**d)

new = dataframe.rdd.map(transform)
```

I suppose you want to remove a lot of fields to keep the records slim, otherwise it doesn't really worth it.

Comment: yeah. I have a big json and just want to output a few fields after filter. Thanks!